# Show/hide user controls with menu items in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, stackpanel

I've created a stack panel on my main window with a dock panel holding the menu and menu items. In the same stack panel I have my 3 user controls. I need to display only one of these 3 user controls when a user clicks a menu item, but my hidden user controls still take up space when they are not shown.

[image]

Between the menu and my visible user control at the bottom, there is another hidden user control that takes up space.

The stack panel in question:

```
<StackPanel>
        <DockPanel>
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <MenuItem Header="Equipment">
                    <MenuItem Header="_List" Click="mnuEquipList_Click" />
                    <MenuItem Header="_Create" Click="mnuEquipCreate_Click" />
                    <MenuItem Header="_Update" Click="mnuEquipUpdate_Click" />
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Click="mnuExit_Click" />
            </Menu>
        </DockPanel>
        <equipment:EquipmentCreateView Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="equipCreateView"></equipment:EquipmentCreateView>
        <equipment:EquipmentListView DataContext="{Binding EquipmentListViewModel}" Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="equipListView"></equipment:EquipmentListView>
        <equipment:EquipmentUpdateView Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="equipUpdateView"></equipment:EquipmentUpdateView>
    </StackPanel>
```

When a user clicks a menu item, the Visibility property is set to true and the others to false. Is there another way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Use `Collapsed` instead of `Hidden`

Answer (score 1):

Simple way: Use "Collapsed" instead "Hidden"

Better way:

ViewModels of your Equipment Views must inhertance from common interface.

```
public class EquipmentCreateViewModel : IEquipment
{
     //...
}

public class EquipmentListViewModel : IEquipment
{
     //...
}
```

You should assign this ViewModels in Property on Main viewmodel when users click buttons by RelayCommands.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
     public IEquipment SelectedEquipment {get;set;}
}
```

On main View you should declare DataTemplate.

Parts of MainView.xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>            
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type equipment:EquipmentCreateViewModel}">
                <equipment:EquipmentCreateView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type equipment:EquipmentListViewModel}">
                <equipment:EquipmentListView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <!--And so on-->            
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```